# Finder does not show files in folders

Tags: macos, finder

When I open Finder all folders seem to be empty. Checking with the console shows that all files are there. This is also true if I try to open a file from within an application using the `File` menu.

If I paste the full path of the file into the text field of the file dialog, the file gets opened.

If I jump to a subfolder with Cmd-Shift-G that works fine. But again the folder is empty.

Any ideas what's missing?

Comment: in all Finders view options ?

Comment: log in as different user to check.

Comment: Silly question - is iTunes up to date?  There was a bug on the ~/users folder that cause people to not have access to their own files recently caused by iTunes (now fixed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After all this turned out to be a side effect from `com.apple.IconServicesAgent` going wild and eating up lots of CPU.

Running `mkdir ${TMPDIR}/com.apple.IconServices` in Terminal solved the problem immediately.

Comment: superb fix. i would have had no idea IconServicesAgent was the culprit

Comment: wow. thanks. this thing was killing my cpu and battery overheating. but all i did was simply kill it from Activity Monitor (in Applications / Utilities folder)  and restarted Finder.

Answer (score 1):

It my case, it was Finder itself that was going wild and eating up lots of CPU. I have no idea why. But killing and restarting the process fixed the issue of empty folders displaying.

In general, I suppose it's a good idea to go into Activity Monitor, see what's eating up CPU and restart anything that's using an unreasonably high level.