# Finder does not update

Tags: macos, finder

I have an issue in a folder were some files, that was recently put there by an installer, does not show in Finder. Files are not hidden (ls -Ol), they show in Terminal, and has the same file permissions as other files in the same folder.
The only difference between the files are that they were recently put there by a .pkg installer.

To refresh the state of files in the folder, I need to use the search-function in Finder. After being searched for, the files become visible.

I looked through AD to check if there were others that has the same issue, but the only question I found was this -  [Finder does not show files in folders](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135379/finder-does-not-show-files-in-folders) and this [What would cause normal files to be hidden from the Finder but not the terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/191973/what-would-cause-normal-files-to-be-hidden-from-the-finder-but-not-the-terminal?rq=1) - and the answers there did not solve my issue.

Did anyone see the same problem as I did and know how to solve it permanently without needing to use the search-function?

I use Yosemite 10.10.5.

Comment: Do the files have a period in front of them? eg: ".MyFile"

Comment: No, it seems like it could be any filename

Comment: Ok, have you tried opening Terminal and typing this command?: chflags nohidden /path/to/hidden/file

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MorganR , but using the chflags utility did not help me. I did not know about the chflags utility. Nice to know if I want to change flags for files.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard of this happening before, but can't put my hands on a link right now.

Try this applescript, save it as an App
It refreshes the contents of all open Finder windows by switching them to another view then back again.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theWindows to every window
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in theWindows
        set this_item to item i of theWindows
        set theView to current view of this_item
        if theView is list view then
            set current view of this_item to icon view
        else
            set current view of this_item to list view          
        end if
        set current view of this_item to theView
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks, but it did not change the visual state of the missing files in Finder. I did not know much about Apple Script - http://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/applescript/info and the Script Editor until now. So Good to learn something else on the way.